# vectorizer my own text data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize some text documents that I have.
Preparing it for a fit() method.

I did quite a bit of search on this and based on all that I saw looks like this is the right code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

filenames = ['aa.txt','bb.txt','cc.txt']

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(filenames)

print ("feature names - ")
print (vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

I was expecting to see the words within the files as my feature names
But instead here is what I see

```
feature names - 
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'txt']
```

I can see this from the documentation - "If ‘filename’, the sequence passed as an argument to fit is expected to be a list of filenames that need reading to fetch the raw content to analyze. "

Answer (score 1):

The default option for that vectorizer is to accept actual text data, not filenames - it's interpreting it as a list of 3 "sentences" containing "words" shown in your feature names.

As seen in the nice manual http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html you should initialize it as TfidfVectorizer(input='filename') to read anything from a file.

Comment: Thanks .. had seen that but am trying to read all files in a directory ... And was trying to work my way onto that